# How to print out specific parts of a string

Tags: java

This is my code and What I need help on is that I do not know how to print out only certain part of string

So what this code is supposed to do is that for example input is say &&&&&& and 456 then the output is supposed to be*** 456 so meaning &&&&&& = print 6 *'s and as many numbers there are meaning length the 's go away so * -> ***456 and if input contains "," for example input is &&&,&&&&&(anywhere is fine for ",") and 10000 then output is 10,000 and so on with "." that puts decimal point where it is placed and round up to that point and "$" just puts a dollar sign in front of the numbers

so my problem is the "," part for example I input 1000000000 and &&&&&&&&,&&&& then it is supposed to print out **1,000,000,000 how would I do this?

So how I am going to make my code is that I make it print out last 3 of the string so it would be 000 and then put a * with a `for (int...` statement and I need help how to make my code to read only the last 3 letters of a string(IT IS THE SECOND IF STATEMENT(`else if (X.contains(",") && !X.contains("."))` THIS ONE)

But I don't think a `for (int...` is going to work any suggestions on about this I would appreciate it Thank you!

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class printFormatting
{

// all the "//"s are to see if the each step works

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter the &'s and ,'s");
    String X = in.next();
    //System.out.println(X);

    System.out.println("Enter the numbers");
    String Y = in.next();
    //System.out.println(Y);

    int lengthX = X.length();
    //System.out.println("Print out length of X");
    //System.out.println(lengthX);

    int lengthY = Y.length();
    //System.out.println("Print out length of Y");
    //System.out.println(lengthY);

    if (X.contains(",") && X.contains("."))
    {
        lengthX -= 2;
        for (int z = lengthX-lengthY; z > 0;)
        {
            System.out.print("*");
            z--;
        }


        //System.out.println("Works , && .");

    }
    else if (X.contains(",") && !X.contains("."))
    {
        lengthX -= 1;
        for (int z = lengthX-lengthY; z > 0;)
        {
            System.out.print("*");
            z--;
        }



        System.out.println(X.length());

        //System.out.println("Works ,");
        //This is to see if , can be seen
    }
    else if (X.contains(".") && !X.contains(","))
    {
        lengthX -= 1;
        for (int z = lengthX-lengthY; z > 0;)
        {
            System.out.print("*");
            z--;
        }

        //System.out.println("Works ,");
        //same
    }
    if (X.contains("$"))
    {
        lengthX -= 1;
        for (int z = lengthX-lengthY; z > 0;)
        {
            System.out.print("*");
            z--;
        }
        System.out.print("$");

        //System.out.println("Works &");
    }

    System.out.println(Y);


}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am a little fuzzy on what you mean with the `,` and where to put it. But I understand that you like to replace the `*` with the number (starting from the end), so that:

```
******   and  123  become ***123
```

**[EDIT]**

then I am just guessing, that whenever the String `x` contains any `,` or `.` you want to have the standard decimal separator ( a , or . dividing always 3 digits of your number), so that

```
   1000 becomes     1,000  
  10000 becomes    10,000
1000000 becomes 1,000,000
```

and so on. I may have misunderstood, so please correct me if I am wrong here. But here is how I would do it:

```
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);  

    System.out.println("Enter the &'s and ,'s");
    String x = in.next();

    System.out.println("Enter the numbers");
    String y = in.next();

    // here begins the new part

    String output = x.replace("&", "*");  // first replace all & with *
    String separator = "";                // check what kind of separator to use (, or .)
    if (x.contains(",")) {
        separator = ",";
        output = output.replace(",", ""); // remove all the , (we won't need them anymore)
    } else if (x.contains(".")) {
        separator = "."; 
        output = output.replace(".", ""); // remove the .
    }

    // now get the substring with the * that you keep and remove as many * as you need for the number
    output = output.substring(0, output.length() - y.length());  
    // just append the number to your output String
    output += y;

    System.out.println("output without the "+separator+"'s :\n"+ output);  // this is just to check if all *s where replaced correctly

    int remainingLength = output.length();    // we start at full length
    while (remainingLength / 3 > 0) {         // at every 3rd digit we want a separator (but not if the number has less only 3 or less digits) 
        // first our failsave: if there is a * in the substring we want to separate by a , or . then we are finished– break the loop and stop 
        if(output.substring(remainingLength - 3).contains("*")){
            break;
        }

        // otherwise form a new string of the substring before the separator, append the separator and the just add the other substring from after the seperator        
        output = output.substring(0, remainingLength - 3) + separator + output.substring(remainingLength - 3);
        remainingLength-=3;  // we just put a , after the 3 next digits          
    }
    System.out.println("output with the "+separator+"'s :\n"+ output);
```

**TEST**

```
Enter the &'s and ,'s
&&&&&,&&&&&
Enter the numbers
10000000
output without the ,'s :
**10000000
output with the ,'s :
**10,000,000
```